# Undecimated wavelet transformation on image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab and I am trying to use the wavelet tool box in Matlab. I hope to use the undecimated wavelet transformation on an input image to create a series of images. But I am wondering how can I get the result of the wavelet transformation of each level?

The function I used in the program is

```
WTSource = ndwt2(Source, n, 'db1');
```

Where Source is the input image, n is the levels of the transformatino and 'db1', or haar transformation, is used to generate the images.

I had thought WTSource.dec is the result images, but I found that the size of the elements in WTSource.dec is different from the input image. And as n increases, the images became larger. So I am wondering how should I get the result images of the transformation for further use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation
 
 http://www.mathworks.nl/help/wavelet/ref/ndwt2.html
after your command:

```
 WTSource= ndwt2(Source,n,'db1');
```

the output `WTSource` is a record with a field `dec` that contains all those fields.

dec{  1  }        approximation level n
dec{2 : 4}     detail        level n-1 (channels LH, HL, HH)
dec{5 : 7}     detail        level n-2 (channels LH, HL, HH)
 ...
dec{3n-1 : 3n+1} detail        level 1  (channels LH, HL, HH)

Each element of `dec` is the same size as your input image.

See also:
 http://www.mathworks.nl/products/wavelet/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/wavelet/ndwtdemo.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, I still found the sizes are different. For example, in the demo 'Multilevel 1-D Non-Decimated Wavelet Decomposition' you provided, we can see that in the struct WT, the member 'longs' is [984 984 983 982 981 980 979]. When images are treated as input, the sizes are also different. I am still wondering about it.

Comment: that has to do with the extension mode (see http://www.mathworks.nl/help/wavelet/ref/ndwt.html which then points to http://www.mathworks.nl/help/wavelet/ref/dwtmode.html). When you're using the db1/Haar wavelet, the signal only needs extending at 1 point/level.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me and now I know what happens now.