# Undecimated discrete wavelet transform using Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet-transform

Loosely based on the above figure:
[image]

I need to make an array like this:

```
array = [(image),(1,ll),(1,lh),(1,hl),(2,ll),(2,lh),(2,hl)]
```

Here, image is a numpy 2D array, and rest other array items are the components obtained by undecimated discrete wavelet transform, which are also 2D arrays.

For eg,

```
(1,ll) is level 1 component,channel low-high
(2,hl) is level 2 component, channel high-low
```

With Python 2.7, this is fairly simple.

```
udwt = np.asarray(pywt.swt2(image, 'haar',2))
array = [image,
         udwt[0][0] ,    #1,ll
         udwt[0][1][0],  #1,lh
         udwt[0][1][1],  #1,hl
         udwt[1][0] ,    #2,ll
         udwt[1][1][0],  #2,lh
         udwt[1][1][1]]  #2,hl
```

However, I am unable to do this in Matlab.

```
udwt = ndwt2(image,2,'haar');
```

Components will be found in `udwt.dec` (`dec` field of `udwt` structure), from `1 to 7`.

Creating parallels from Python code:

```
Python                               Matlab
udwt[0][0]                         My question
udwt[0][1][0]                      udwt.dec{5}
udwt[0][1][1]                      udwt.dec{6}
udwt[1][0]                         udwt.dec{1}
udwt[1][1][0]                      udwt.dec{2}
udwt[1][1][1]                      udwt.dec{3}

(Python's function gives components from level 1 to level n.
 Matlab's function gives components from level n to level 1.(reverse order))
```

The problem is, I am not getting the **low-low component (approximation component)of 1st level** in Matlab (1,ll).

On using `ndwt2` for 2 level decomposition, it gives me only one approximation and 3 details for each level (lh,hl,hh).

Whereas in Python's [pywt.swt2()](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/swt-stationary-wavelet-transform.html#multilevel-swt2), I get an approximation for each level, and 3 details(lh,hl,hh) for each level.

so where am I to find this 1,ll in Matlab?

I consider `udwt.dec{1}` to be 2,ll (low-low of 2nd level instead of 1st level based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811246/undecimated-wavelet-transformation-on-image-using-matlab).

```
dec{ 1 }        approximation level n
```

Shall I be using some other function instead of `ndwt2`?